# selenium crashing because of undefined js function

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I am tying to open a website with selenium

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My Java code looks like this:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get("https://somewebsite.com");
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function getElementsByClassName in object [object HTMLDivElement]. (https://somewebsite.com/Layout/General/lic-notification.js#245)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:637)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:612)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1001)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:179)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:239)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:824)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:748)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$1.run(HtmlElement.java:920)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:925)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1298)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:290)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:475)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:342)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:480)
```

It seems to me, that the getElementByClassname function is not defined in selenium's JS engine which is in contrast to several posts around the web where this function is used in order to access hidden input elements.
Am I doing something wrong or is it a error in selenium?

EDIT:
This is the JS-Function causing the crash. I didn't write it on my own, I am just accessing the website to do some repetitive tasks.

```
var getPendingContainter = function () {
    var e, d;
    if (!(e = document.getElementById("nPendingContainer"))) {
        e = ce("div"); sa(e, "id", "nPendingContainer");
        sa(e, "style", "display:none;");
        ac(document.body, e);
        m = ce("div"); cn(m, "marker"); ac(e, m);
        d = ce("div"); cn(d, "inner"); ac(e, d);
    } else {
        d = document.getElementById("nPendingContainer").getElementsByClassName("inner")[0];
    }
    return d;
}
```

EDIT2:
Debugging the site shows, that this function is called by jQuery using the .ready() function. I don't know if it helps. My Chrome doesn't give me any error.

Comment: Can you provide more detail of the code around the JS file at https://somewebsite.com/Layout/General/lic-notification.js#245, please? It looks like you're calling getElementsByClassName from an instance of HTMLDivElement rather than from Document.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with selenium, but wouldn't this rather be a limitation of the HtmlUnitDriver you're using? If you would test selenium directly with a browser driver such as ChromeDriver, does the problem then go away? The documentation hints that the results with HtmlUnitDriver will be very different: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver

Comment: Using the ChromeDriver made the problem disappear, but unfortunately I doesn't get rid of the browser window. Using a PhantomJS driver made it even worse for me.